# The existence of $n$-sided cells in regular $m$-gons

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

For any integer $n >= 3$, does there exist a regular
$m$-gon with all diagonals drawn containing a cell with $n$ sides?
See [A342222](https://oeis.org/A342222) and its cross-references.
[Regular polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon) on the Wiki.

---

[image]

          

<sup>The image from Scott R. Shannon illustrates the case $n=14$.</sup>

---

Comment: It's perhaps worth mentioning explicitly (as stated in the OEIS entry) that even the answer to the following much weaker question seems to be unknown: Does there exist $m$ such that the diagram of a regular $m$-gon contains a 16-sided cell? (And maybe even the following is unknown: Does there exist $m$ such that the diagram of a regular $m$-gon contains a $2k$-gon with $k\ge 16$?)